# How to conform to protocol in Swift?

Tags: swift

I try to convert facebookSDK method to swift code:

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                        user:`(id<FBGraphUser>)user {}
```

The problem is with this:

```
id<FBGraphUser>)user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<>` is in Objective-C: conforms to protocol

`<>` is in Swift for generics

---

If you only want to conform that the type of user is id and conforms to the protocol FBGraphUser:

id is AnyObject in Swift.

You can use protocols as types in the declarations of variable names.

```
func loginViewFetchedUserInfo<T where T: AnyObject, T: FBGraphUser>(loginView: FBLoginView, #user: T)
{
   ...
}
// use the # only if you want the call of the method to write 'user:'
```

#### Using the method:

That is even easier. First you need the object which has the method, let's call it `facebookObject`. Now, if you have a variable `myUser` with the type `AnyObject, FBGraphUser`. And a variable `myLoginView` of type `FBLoginView`. Then you call the method with

```
facebookObject.loginViewFetchedUserInfo(loginView: myLoginView, user: myLoginView)
```

it could be that the `user:` is not required, since that is the normal pattern for methods.

---

You can however do more with the `where` keyword

> Use **where** after the type name to specify a list of requirements—for example, to require the type to implement a protocol, to require two types to be the same, or to require a class to have a particular superclass.

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” [iBooks](https://itun.es/de/jEUH0.l).

Comment: can you show me how to use in the method i post?

Comment: ok, i don't have error but the method not called..

Comment: Of course, I thought you want to declare it. I showed you how to declare such a method

Comment: yes i know, but nothing happen when i run my app

Comment: I added how to use the method. Since I think you simply want to call a facebookSDK method.

Comment: still not work :( can you wrote to full code? thank you very much!!!!!

Comment: It isn't even clear what you want. You should update your question with more detail info.